# Open specific files with my Windows Store application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm developing a Media Player `Windows Store` app, I need to make this app be suggested by Windows when the user tries to open a media file, I never tried to do this on other platforms (WPF, WindowsForms) I know that there are answers around here explaining how to do that in those technologies, but I'm new to this and I'm not sure if it works the same, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the file types you support in the manifest (you can do this in VS) and then add a handler for when your app is launched this way.
See here for the details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh779669.aspx